# Linking System with database

Tags: python

I have been learning Python and I have a system that I need linked to a database. It is more of an attendance system thus I would like a database linked to it such that when I save current records it automatically updates on the database. Please Assist.

Comment: A little more information on the system that you have (SQL server maybe?), and anything you've already attempted would help. The more information the better.

Comment: Do you have a database already ? What you wanne do with it? What kind of system ? Edit: Your edit on the question, sounds more like you looking for a log then a database imo. If you want a decent answer you need to give more info.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Management Studio 2017 has the ability to run external Python scripts right in the database. If you want to keep the data and computation mostly in SQL, this is probably your best bet.

Otherwise, you can connect to SQL Server from Python with a variety of libraries like [SQLite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: Would be strange to run external python script :P. I recommand your second option. Explain how he can achieve that.

Comment: A link has been attached with more details